# VBA using if statement and for loop to merge certain cells

Tags: vba, excel, merge

I am trying to get this code to say "if the cell in column 3 (C) = the word "high" or "middle" then merge and center the matching cell in column 4 (D) with only the cell below it. However, the way mine reacts now is by merging all the way to the bottom because of .End(xlDown). I'm not sure how to fix that. Here a sample of the data and how I want it to look:

[example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZGER.png)

Here is the VBA code I've been using:

```
Sub Merge_Priority2()
Dim RgToMerge As String


For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
    RgToMerge = ""
    If LCase(Cells(i, 3)) = "high" Or LCase(Cells(i, 3)) = "middle" Then
       RgToMerge = "$D$" & Cells(i, 4).End(xlDown).Row & ":$D$" & i
       With Range(RgToMerge)
           .Merge
           .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
           .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
       End With

    Else
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I would think just remove `.End(xlDown)`.

Comment: no it just centers the cell it doesn't merge then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you were using that `.End(xlDown)` in order to select down one row, but you could get rid of that (as @MattCremeens suggests). Then, for the second part of your range, add 1 to `i` to get it to select *only one* row down, like so:

```
RgToMerge = "$D$" & i & ":$D$" & i + 1
```

For row 1, the `RgToMerge` will then look like `$D$1:$D$2`. The complete Sub would look like this:

```
Sub Merge_Priority2()
Dim RgToMerge As String


For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
    RgToMerge = ""
    If LCase(Cells(i, 3)) = "high" Or LCase(Cells(i, 3)) = "middle" Then
       RgToMerge = "$D$" & i & ":$D$" & i + 1
       With Range(RgToMerge)
           .Merge
           .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
           .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
       End With

    Else
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

try just defining the range based on your row variable (i)

```
Sub Merge_Priority2()
Dim RgToMerge As Range


For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    If LCase(Cells(i, 3)) = "high" Or LCase(Cells(i, 3)) = "middle" Then
    Set RgToMerge = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(i, 4), Cells(i + 1, 4))

       With RgToMerge
           .Merge
           .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
           .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
       End With

    Else
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your code slightly. I don't feel you were too far off.

Sub Merge_Priority2()
Dim RgToMerge As Range

```
For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    If LCase(Cells(i, 3)) = "high" Or LCase(Cells(i, 3)) = "middle" Then
       Set RgToMerge = Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i + 1, 3))
       With RgToMerge
           .Merge
           .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
           .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
       End With

    Else
    End If

Next i
```

I'm assuming the relevant data is in column C.
End Sub